# Unable to import pandas in ipython notebook even after installing correctly on MAC OSX El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have installed pandas through conda install pandas and still receiving this error while importing the pandas library through ipython jupyter notebook.

I have also tried to check the version mismatch through

```
print ('version:' + np.__version__)
```

and have traced the path to the sys.executable directory from this

```
sys.executable
for x in sys.path: print (x)
```

and have the correct path to data directory.

```
from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_data_dir
print(jupyter_data_dir())
```

### import pandas as pd

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-af55e7023913> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     42 import pandas.core.config_init
     43 
---> 44 from pandas.core.api import *
     45 from pandas.sparse.api import *
     46 from pandas.stats.api import *

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py in <module>()
      7 from pandas.core.common import isnull, notnull
      8 from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
----> 9 from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
     10 from pandas.core.format import set_eng_float_format
     11 from pandas.core.index import Index, CategoricalIndex, Int64Index, Float64Index, MultiIndex

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in <module>()
     15 from pandas.core.base import PandasObject
     16 from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
---> 17 from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
     18 from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame
     19 from pandas.core.index import Index, MultiIndex, CategoricalIndex, _ensure_index

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in <module>()
     39                                    create_block_manager_from_arrays,
     40                                    create_block_manager_from_blocks)
---> 41 from pandas.core.series import Series
     42 from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
     43 import pandas.computation.expressions as expressions

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in <module>()
   2907 # Add plotting methods to Series
   2908 
-> 2909 import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx
   2910 
   2911 Series.plot = base.AccessorProperty(_gfx.SeriesPlotMethods, _gfx.SeriesPlotMethods)

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in <module>()
     26 from pandas.util.decorators import Appender
     27 try:  # mpl optional
---> 28     import pandas.tseries.converter as conv
     29     conv.register()  # needs to override so set_xlim works with str/number
     30 except ImportError:

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tseries/converter.py in <module>()
      5 from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
      6 
----> 7 import matplotlib.units as units
      8 import matplotlib.dates as dates
      9 

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
   1129 
   1130 # this is the instance used by the matplotlib classes
-> 1131 rcParams = rc_params()
   1132 
   1133 if rcParams['examples.directory']:

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in rc_params(fail_on_error)
    973         return ret
    974 
--> 975     return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
    976 
    977 

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error, use_default_template)
   1098         parameters specified in the file. (Useful for updating dicts.)
   1099     """
-> 1100     config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
   1101 
   1102     if not use_default_template:

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
   1016     cnt = 0
   1017     rc_temp = {}
-> 1018     with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
   1019         try:
   1020             for line in fd:

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
     57     def __enter__(self):
     58         try:
---> 59             return next(self.gen)
     60         except StopIteration:
     61             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in _open_file_or_url(fname)
    998     else:
    999         fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)
-> 1000         encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
   1001         if encoding is None:
   1002             encoding = "utf-8"

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/locale.py in getdefaultlocale(envvars)
    557     else:
    558         localename = 'C'
--> 559     return _parse_localename(localename)
    560 
    561 

/Users/amitanshu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/locale.py in _parse_localename(localename)
    485     elif code == 'C':
    486         return None, None
--> 487     raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
    488 
    489 def _build_localename(localetuple):

ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following parameters to your `~/.bash_profile` (by typing the below into `terminal`):

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```